# Can't refresh ListView on Android. notifyDataSetChanged() isn't working

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I'm trying to create a simple random number generator and everything works well, instead of updating the ListView when I generate new numbers. Array, Adapter and ListView are connected properly, cause if values are added to the array before connecting it to adapter, ListView shows them correctly. I tried different ways to clear the adapter etc., but it just make app crash. I know that before (I haven't used Kotlin for a couple of months) everything worked well when I added only `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I wish someone will find out what's going on.

### MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.randomnumber

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var fromTextEdit : EditText
    lateinit var toTextEdit : EditText
    lateinit var amountTextEdit : EditText
    lateinit var generatedListView: ListView
    lateinit var generateButton : Button

    var generatedArray : ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()

    lateinit public var arrayAdapter : ArrayAdapter<Int>

    fun clickGenerate (view : View) {

        Log.i("generateButton", "Button clicked")

        generatedArray.clear()

        if (fromTextEdit.text.toString() != "" && toTextEdit.text.toString() != "" && amountTextEdit.text.toString() != "") {

            var amount = Integer.parseInt(amountTextEdit.text.toString())

            if (Integer.parseInt(fromTextEdit.text.toString()) < Integer.parseInt(toTextEdit.text.toString())) {
                Log.i("From", Integer.parseInt(fromTextEdit.text.toString()).toString())
                Log.i("To", Integer.parseInt(toTextEdit.text.toString()).toString())
                for (i in 0 until amount) {
                    generatedArray.add(
                        Random.nextInt(
                            Integer.parseInt(fromTextEdit.text.toString()),
                            Integer.parseInt(toTextEdit.text.toString()) + 1
                        )
                    )
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter all values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        for (i in generatedArray) {
            Log.i("Generated", i.toString())
        }

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fromTextEdit = findViewById(R.id.fromEditText)
        toTextEdit = findViewById(R.id.toEditText)
        amountTextEdit = findViewById(R.id.amountEditText)
        generatedListView = findViewById(R.id.generatedListView)
        generateButton = findViewById(R.id.generateButton)

        generatedArray.add(5)
        generatedArray.add(5)
        generatedArray.add(5)
        generatedArray.add(5)
        generatedArray.add(5)
        generatedArray.add(5)

        arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, generatedArray.toList())

        generatedListView.adapter = arrayAdapter

    }
}
```

Comment: How is `clickGenerate()` called? Are you setting `clickGenerate` in the `android:onClick` in `R.layout.activity_main`?

Comment: Yep, and it's printing out everything out to the Logcat properly.

Comment: I suspect calling `generatedArray.toList()` is the culprit. It will create an entirely new object, so it is different from the instance which gets updated when you call `clickGenerate()`, so `notifyDataSetChanged()` will have no effect, since the original list actually doesn't change.

To test this, make sure you update the same instance of list that the adapter uses. You can do this by avoiding the call to `generatedArray.toList()`

In general, there are some improvements that can still be made to the piece of code you have up there in order to make debugging easier. @David

Comment: Okay, thanks @SegunFamisa, I'll try it out when I'll have a minute